# dyld[13932]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RLMApp and crashes

Tags: xcode, realm

Using Xcode 15.1 and Realm 10.44.0 ( I tried 10.45.3 as well), my iOS app compiled but crash immediately at the start.

I get this message in the console:

```
dyld[13932]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RLMApp Referenced from: <997641DE-4DC0-3C9B-8703-EB619E0EA798> 
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/895CD321-AC24-400E-94D7-E7D113BA6F6A/LibreLink.app/Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift   Expected in:     <5BA15EC4-BF30-38AB-9B9C-565F0C50612C> 
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/895CD321-AC24-400E-94D7-E7113BA6F6A/LibreLink.app/Frameworks/Realm.framework/Real
m
```

and the stack trace:

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFvnK.png)

My app was running fine with XCODE 14.1, Realm 10.34.1 until we switch to Xcode 15.1 (and 15.2 as well)

I installed Realm in a library I build using Carthage. I then used that library in my app. I also use Realm on the app side but using Realm pre-compiled from GitHub (I make sure I use the right Xcode version). I don’t use Carthage on the app side.

Here is the content (4level deep) of my "Realm" directory:

`Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/RealmSwift.framework/_CodeSignature
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/RealmSwift.framework/Headers
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/RealmSwift.framework/Modules
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/RealmSwift.framework
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64/RealmSwift.framework/Headers
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64/RealmSwift.framework/Modules
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64/RealmSwift.framework
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework/ios-arm64
Realm/RealmSwift.xcframework
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Realm.framework/_CodeSignature
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Realm.framework/Headers
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Realm.framework/Modules
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator/Realm.framework
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64/Realm.framework/PrivateHeaders
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64/Realm.framework/Headers
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64/Realm.framework/Modules
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64/Realm.framework
Realm/Realm.xcframework/ios-arm64
Realm/Realm.xcframework`

Realm and RealmSwift are also included in a Copy to Framework build phase.

[image: Embedded frameworks]

Also in the general Panel (Embedded content):

[image]

Any help appreciated.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, stack traces, errors and structures as *text*, not links and images. Images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Answer (score 0):

> My app was running fine with XCODE 14.1, **Realm 10.34.1**

Ah, I am pretty sure that Realm version is out of date and needs to be updated. With XCode 15 and above, I believe Realm 10.40.0 is needed along with iOS 12 or above. You may need a Carthage update as well.

See [XCode 15 requirements](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/install/#xcode-15)

Comment: As I tried to explain, poorly I presume now, I’m not using Carthage (always installed from the pre-compiled release from GitHub)  and I did update both Xcode to 15.1 and Realm to 10.45.2 (and also tried with latest 10.45.3).  my iOS minimum is set to 15.5.

Comment: @Pitoneux Understood and I don't think Carthage is the cause. The question specifically states `Realm 10.34.1` which as you can see by my answer *would* be the cause of some issues. If that's not the case, please update the question with current details and we'll take another look. By any chance, have you just removed your install of Realm completely and tried a Cocoapods (my preference) install or SPM? Both of those have been very reliable for us creating hundreds of projects. You can go back and change that later but just as a test to see if it resolves the issue.